# Is MultiDrawElementsBaseVertex bound by index type?

Tags: opengl

With `glMultiDrawElementsBaseVertex` it becomes possible to render multiple sets of indices in one draw call. When using for instance `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` as the type of the indices is there still a restriction that only `MAX_UNSIGNED_SHORT` vertices can be rendered at a time? Or does the combination with multiple base vertices allow to exceed this number and allow for multiple sets of sub-draw calls provided that these do not exceed the `MAX_UNSIGNED_SHORT` restriction in relation to their base vertex?

So for instance given the following input to the command:

$\mathit{count} = [65535, 65535]$

$\mathit{indices} = [\mathit{indexOffset0}, \mathit{indexOffset1}]$

$\mathit{baseVertex} = [0, 65536]$

will the baseVertex offset (> `MAX_UNSIGNED_SHORT`) be correctly added to the index found at indexOffset1? I don't believe the specs raise anything about the types of indices used and the number of vertices referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When using for instance `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` as the type of the indices is there still a restriction that only `MAX_UNSIGNED_SHORT` vertices can be rendered at a time

No such restriction has ever existed (and I checked old versions of the specification). The limitations on `count` have never been related to the size of the index type. The type of the indices only describes the type of the *indices*; how many indices are being used is specified by `count` and is unrelated to the type.